# WebBrowser control: Navigate shows error message box even though .Silent is true

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, atl

I am hosting a web browser control, initialized with `IWebBrowser2.put_Silent(VARIANT_TRUE)`.

However, when calling `IWebBrowser2.Navigate`with a malformed path, I still get a message box to the equivalent of

> "file:///D://htmlstuff/page.html" was not found. Make sure the path or internet address is correct.

The issue here is the accidental double-slash specified by the user (D:\htmlstuff instead of D:\htmlstuff).

I can catch this particular problem earlier, before doing the Navigate, but I'm concerned that this message box still occurs, as I cannot verify every possible URL (or other possible cause that makes the webbrowser control ignore the Silent flag).

I would expect to get an error code returned silently.

Any ideas? Is there a "even more silent" option?

Windows 8.0, IE 10.0.9200.16750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling [`NavigateError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268221%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event on the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX control. I have [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20902928/1768303) showing how handle the "underlying" `WebBrowser` events like that. It's for WPF, but it can be easily adapter for WinForms (using `WebBrowser.ActiveXInstance`).

Alternatively, I think you should be able to handle this kind of messages by implementing [`IDocHostShowUI::ShowMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684075/1768303) showing how to implement `IDocHostUIHandler` on `WebBrowser` site object. The same approach can be used for `IDocHostShowUI`.

Disclaimer: I haven't verified either of these two potential solutions.

Comment: Thanks! - I tried NavigateError, but it doesn't trigger. IDocHostSHowUI seems to be harder to implement, as it needs to be implemented on the object that also implements IOleClientSite, according to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753269(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I haven't messed with it in a loooooooong while, but look at this: [WebBrowserEx - Extended WebBrowser Control](http://webbrowserex.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @peterchen, you can subclass the base's `IOleClientSite`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19717787/1768303

Comment: @Noseratio: C++/ATL unfortunately (I've fixed the misleading tags). https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.vc.atl/tPB41rx6XAs/W3tjg53EDpwJ is the closest I can find. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @peterchen, no problem. I have another [code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18334802/1768303) which may help doing this with ATL :) If `IDocHostSHowUI` does work, you can always resort to [CBTHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is a nasty behavior of the WebBrowser control, which I experience with VBA and UserForms.
My workaround was to load the target URL into an iframe within a small hosting page. This
way no alert pops up, and you can query if the target URL did indeed load or not.

Call the hosting page with `<PathTo>/framehost.html#<TargetURL>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Frame Host</title>
    <script>

window.onload = function() {
    var frame = document.getElementById('MyFrame');
    frame.src = location.hash.substring(1);
    frame.onload = function() {
        try {
            var doc = frame.contentDocument;
            alert("Loaded " + frame.src);
        } catch(e) {
            alert("Failed to load " + frame.src)
        }
    }
}

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="MyFrame" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```